# How to get rid of repeated Data?

Tags: c#, .net

There is a function like that:

```
public List<Point> FindNextPoint(List<Point> source, Point point, List<Point> findedPoints)
    {
        List<Point> result = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> points = source.FindAll(
            delegate (Point i)
            {
                return (Math.Abs(i.X - point.X) <= 2 && Math.Abs(i.Y - point.Y) <= 2) && !findedPoints.Contains(i);
            }
            );
        result.AddRange(points);
        findedPoints.AddRange(points);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            List<Point> findPoints = FindNextPoint(source, points[i], findedPoints);
            result.AddRange(findedPoints);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

but it returns many repeated Point in the list,how to get rid of if?Thank you

I mean that everytime I run the function it will return a List,I wonder if there any chance that return a List not including the data before.

for example. I first run the function it returns a value including the Point{x=0,y=1},when I run the function for the second time it will not return the same Point returned before,and will also not FindAll to find it.

Comment: System.Drawing.Point

Comment: So when you are adding in `result` using AddRange before that apply distinct and add it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding `findPoints` to `result` instead of `findedPoints`?  Also you might want to make `findedPoints` a `HashSet` to be more efficient.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are trying to do something like A* for pathfinding... Maybe if you mention what you *actually* trying to do someone would suggest more sensible approach (usually you'd drop new points to stack or queue and only check those)

Comment: To Alexei Levenkov :Yes I'im trying to do something like pathfinding.I know all the points arount a object but there is many object and I do not know which point belongs to which object.

Comment: Look at @juharr 's comment, seems you made a mistake..

Comment: just an english spelling notation: you may want to use `foundPoints` name instead of `findedPoints`

Answer (score 0):

When returning data you should use this Code:

```
return result.Distinct();
```

and don't forget to add the code below on top otherwise you cannot see the Distinct function:

```
using System.Linq;
```